# Need to Check if a particular location is within the boundaries of the map

Tags: android, android-mapview, osmdroid

i use osmdroid MapView.
I need to find if user Location in within the boundaries of the map (depends the zoom level).

I try to user MapView.getBoundingBox().contain(location).. But it seems that the getBoundingBox() returns the Visible boundaries.

is there a way to get the original Map boundaries (depends the zoom level)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can find out the latitude and longitude of the northwest and southeast corners
of your mapview with code like:

```
GeoPoint topLeftGpt     = (GeoPoint) mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(0, 0);
GeoPoint bottomRightGpt = (GeoPoint) mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
            mapView.getWidth(), mapView.getHeight());
```

You can then find out if the point of interest falls within these bounds.

Answer (score 1):

For v2:

```
    LatLng northwest  = (LatLng) mMap.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(new Point(0, 0));
    LatLng southeast = (LatLng) mGoogleMap.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(
        new Point(mMapView.getWidth(), mMapView.getHeight()));
```